# What is the method that operates on the return value of $() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What is the method that operates on the return value of $() in jQuery?
I think it is show() but I am confused. please if it false than give me the right answer...

Comment: start here: http://api.jquery.com/  but more concisely, $() is typically a wrapper around a dom object(s) so any jquery function used to manipulate or extend the dom object will work off of the $().

Answer (score 1):

$("selecter") return jquery DOM element object.
you can use any valid properties and methods of jquery to access it.

```
//To show div element
$("#divid").show();
//To hide div element
$("#divid").hide();
```

You can get more details at [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com)